# Ignore specific commit but stay in head

Tags: git

I have repo with many commits.

I want to stay on `head` branch but ignore specific commit.

For example:

I've done 10 commits (I locate on `head` branch) and I want to ignore commit number 8.

Comment: I don't understand: `git revert` was the *first* answer I proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your commit hash using `git log`
Now you can use the simple git command

```
git revert <commit>
```

Comment: I proposed that already, and gran33 already told that wasn't the goal.

Comment: thats how i understood it :\

Answer (score 3):

One clean way would be to do a [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert):

```
 git revert HEAD~8
```

That would create a new commit which would cancel the changes introduced by the revision done 8 commits before HEAD.

This other way is to do an [interactive rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~9
```

And drop the 8th commit.

That would change the SHA1 of the other commits though. That can ben an issue if you had already pushed that repo and other people had already cloned it.

Or, as [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) comments, the non-interactive version:

```
git rebase --onto HEAD~9 HEAD~8
```

With recent Git versions, you can replace `HEAD` wit `@`:

```
git rebase --onto @~9 @~8
```

Comment: First 10x, but It doesn't achieve my goal, I want all previous commits without the specific commit number 8.

Comment: @gran33 ok, then the other option os an interactive rebase.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an interactive rebase, a single command suffices: `git rebase --onto HEAD~9 HEAD~8`.